# Lighten instead of darken the background of a button

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

In Zurb foundation, it is possible to change the hover effect to light a link up by adjusting the `$anchor-font-color-hover` from `darken()` to `lighten()` in the `_settings.sass` file.

But for buttons (and other backgrounds) there is no such option. How do I make the hover effects of all buttons to be `lighten` instead of `darken`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `button-style` mixin in `_buttons.scss`:

```
@mixin button-style($bg:$primary-color, $radius:false, $disabled:false) {
  ...
    &:hover,
    &:focus { background-color: lighten($bg, $button-function-factor);
  ... }
```

See [Github](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_buttons.scss#L109)